# What is the meaning of + at the beginning and at the end of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

What is the meaning of + in:

```
document.write("O quadrado de "**+numeros[i]+** " é "**+quadrado+**"<br>");
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with objects, it's just string concatenation. `"hello " + "my" + " friend" === "hello my friend"` You can do the same with `x = "my"; "hello " + x + " friend"`

Comment: It is the [addition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition). This operator will concatenate strings, or, if presented with numbers, add them.

Comment: Hi Vinicius. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question was probably voted down because it contained too much irrelevant information. Try to keep your questions precise. In this case, just the `document.write` line of code was required. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be string concatenation.
more here in part titled "Concatenating strings"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings

Comment: It is most definitely string concatenation, since it will not produce a number here.